# Locust FastHttpUser class requests get 422 status code

Tags: python, testing, python-requests, load-testing, locust

I'm using `Locust` library for my load tests. Everything works pretty well but when I try to replace my `HttpUser` class with `FastHttpUser` class, all of my requests fail with a 422 status code. This is quite peculiar because my request body doesn't change and according to their doc, both user class have the same client API.

For example - This works:

```
class MyUser(HttpUser):
   @task
   def my_task(self):
       self.client.get('/login', data={'username': username, 'password': password})
```

This doesn't work -

```
   class MyUser(FastHttpUser):
   @task
   def my_task(self):
       self.client.get('/login', data={'username': username, 'password': password})
```

Same request. Any idea?

Comment: I think you should send the request using the json parameter not data. If you use json parameter it will add application-json headers.

Comment: There may be some subtle differences. See if you can print the actual request in both cases, and/or check your server logs.

Comment: @MuhammedTanır I tried with `json` key arg as well. Still 422...